# Android convert date and time to milliseconds

Tags: android, datetime

I have one date and time format as below:

```
Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013
```

I want to convert into milliseconds, but I actually dont know which format it is. Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> Update for [DateTimeFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter?hl=en) introduced in API 26.

Code can be written as below for API 26 and above

```
// Below Imports are required for this code snippet
// import java.util.Locale;
// import java.time.LocalDateTime;
// import java.time.ZoneOffset;
// import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
String date = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
long timeInMilliseconds = localDate.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
Log.d(TAG, "Date in milli :: FOR API >= 26 >>> " + timeInMilliseconds);
// Output is -> Date in milli :: FOR API >= 26 >>> 1366733308000
```

But as of now only 6% of devices are running on 26 or above. So you will require backward compatibility for above classes. [JakeWharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) has been written [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which is based on [ThreeTenBP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp), but specially developed to work on Android. *Read more about [How and Why ThreeTenABP should be used instead-of java.time, ThreeTen-Backport, or even Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)*

So using ThreeTenABP, above code can be written as (and verified on API 16 to API 29)

```
// Below Imports are required for this code snippet
// import java.util.Locale;
// import org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime;
// import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
String givenDateString = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013";
long timeInMilliseconds = OffsetDateTime.parse(givenDateString, formatter)
        .toInstant()
        .toEpochMilli();
System.out.println("Date in milli :: USING ThreeTenABP >>> " + timeInMilliseconds);
// Output is -> Date in milli :: USING ThreeTenABP >>> 1366713508000
```

Ole covered summarised information (for Java too) in his answer, you should look into.

---

> Below is old approach (and previous version of this answer) which
>   should not be used now

Use below method

```
String givenDateString = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
    Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
    long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
    System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
} catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Read more about [date and time pattern strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Perfect answer. working 100% for all android platform. Keep it up bro

Comment: i get a date and time from server api  i tried all answer above two give me a error  which is   java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-03-05 09:18:07' could not be parsed at index 10. and last one is giving me answer 51 year ago. i dont understand why

Comment: @Adnanhaider Formatter would  be different for this date.

Comment: You can use code `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled` which offers backward compatibility without needing third party library

Answer (score 13):

try this...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 
             timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 12):

**You can use this code**

```
long miliSecsDate = milliseconds ("2015-06-04");
Log.d("miliSecsDate", " = "+miliSecsDate);

    public long milliseconds(String date) 
    {
        //String date_ = date;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try
        {
            Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
            long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
            System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
            return timeInMilliseconds;
        }
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

**In Kotlin,**

Just use

```
timeInMilSeconds = date.time
```

where `timeInMilSeconds` is milliseconds(`var timeInMilSeconds: Long`) and `date` is [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date)

Answer (score 2):

```
Date beginupd = new Date(cursor1.getLong(1));
```

This variable beginupd contains the format

```
Wed Oct 12 11:55:03 GMT+05:30 2011

long millisecond = beginupd.getTime();

Date.getTime() JavaDoc states:
```

Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Answer (score 2):

Covert date and time string to milliseconds:

```
 public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
```

or

```
  public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
```

or

```
  public static final String DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
  //TimeZone.getAvailableIds() to list all timezone ids
  String timeZone = "EST5EDT";//it can be anything timezone like IST, GMT.
  String time = "2/21/2018 7:41:00 AM";

 public static long[] convertTimeInMillis(String dateTimeFormat, String timeZone, String... times) throws ParseException {

   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat, Locale.getDefault());
   dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
   long[] ret = new long[times.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      String timeWithTZ = times[i] + " "+timeZone;
      Date d = dateFormat.parse(timeWithTZ);
      ret[i] = d.getTime();
    }
  return ret;

}
```

//millis to dateString

```
  public static String convertTimeInMillisToDateString(long timeInMillis, String DATE_TIME_FORMAT) {
     Date d = new Date(timeInMillis);
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
     return sdf.format(d);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I am providing the modern answer — though not more modern than it works on your Android API  level too.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
    String givenDateString = "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013";
    long timeInMilliseconds = OffsetDateTime.parse(givenDateString, formatter)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(timeInMilliseconds);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 1366713508000

The `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` classes used in most of the other answers are poorly designed and now long outdated. I recommend that instead you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Edit: The other answers were fine answers when the question was asked in 2013. Only time moves on, and we should not use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` any more.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Kotlin,

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val UniqueID = calendar.timeInMillis
```

same code in Java,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android 26 and higher**

```
Conversation from epoch to UTC date time and Device date time

public class TimeConversionUtil {

public static long getCurrentEpochUTC() {
    return Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC()).toEpochMilli();
}

public static String deviceDateTimeString(long epochMilliUtc) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilliUtc);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return formatter.format(instant);
}

public static String uTCDateTimeString(long epochMilliUtc) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilliUtc);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    return formatter.format(instant);

}

public static long convertDateStringToLongUTC(String stringUTCDate) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(stringUTCDate, formatter);
    long timeInMilliseconds = localDate.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    return timeInMilliseconds;
}
```

}

```
@Test
public void timeConversionTest() {
    long currentTimeUtc = Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC()).toEpochMilli();
    String utc = TimeConversionUtil.uTCDateTimeString(currentTimeUtc);
    Long utcLongTime = TimeConversionUtil.convertDateStringToLongUTC(utc);
    String utc1 = TimeConversionUtil.uTCDateTimeString(utcLongTime);
    assertTrue(utc.equalsIgnoreCase(utc1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the given answers, if you need to convert the time given by the date to other time units you can use the [TimeUnit API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit)

Example:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
```