# Android Date worng conversion date into millis

Tags: android, date, milliseconds

I got such an issue. I save a `Date (yyyy,mm,dd`). From this date I need to get its `millisec` representation, but when I call `getTime()` it gives me wrong time. Where is the issue?

```
Example :        
Date testDate= new Date (2015,5,11);
```

When I try to call this date millisec, testDate.getTime()

```
result=61392117600000, but it must be result=1433970000000
```

Note : 5 means Jun, because it counts from 0

Comment: It's no fun working with java `Date` objects. Maybe you want to consider working with JodaTime for example in your project: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the Date Class under package `java.util;` the date method add year from `1900` as

```
/**
 * Constructs a new {@code Date} initialized to midnight in the default {@code TimeZone} on
 * the specified date.
 *
 * @param year
 *            the year, 0 is 1900.
 * @param month
 *            the month, 0 - 11.
 * @param day
 *            the day of the month, 1 - 31.
 *
 * @deprecated Use {@link GregorianCalendar#GregorianCalendar(int, int, int)} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public Date(int year, int month, int day) {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(false);
    cal.set(1900 + year, month, day);
    milliseconds = cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

So you need to change

```
Date testDate= new Date (2015,5,11);
```

to

```
Date testDate= new Date (115,5,11);
```

Recommended way is to use `SimpleDateFormat` as given below.

[Android convert date and time to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419374/android-convert-date-and-time-to-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

> year - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)

From JavaDoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Therefore instead of year 2015 you would use 2015 - 1900 = 115  as your year parameter