# How to send data to calendar

Tags: android

I try to add an event in my calendar using this code :

```
Calendar calendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
i.putExtra("beginTime", dataexp);
i.putExtra("allDay", true);
i.putExtra("rule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
i.putExtra("title", tip);
startActivity(i);
```

In the key "beginTime" I want to set a data from a variable "dataexp" which is a string formated from 08-10-2017 . In calendar I receive wrong value for beginTime.

**Edit:** i found a solution at this post M.Ganji answer : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419374/android-convert-date-and-time-to-milliseconds)
This is the code   :

```
 long givenDateString = milliseconds (datacalendar);

            Calendar calendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                i.putExtra("beginTime",givenDateString);
                i.putExtra("allDay", true);
                i.putExtra("rule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
                i.putExtra("endTime", givenDateString);
                i.putExtra("title", "Expira ");
                startActivity(i);
public long milliseconds(String date)
{       
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try
    {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
        long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();          
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

or try this:-

```
long dataexp = System.currentTimeMillis();
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, dataexp);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @cvmircea  add long format dataexp in Timemillis and  try sending it

Comment: I dont want current date, i need a date from a var and i dont know how to format in Timemillis.